# What to supply as argument of createEJBstubs bat on websphere

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.0, stub

If we write a ant build script and use the command createEJBStubs.bat to create EJB stubs, as the argument to the commnad, do we just need to supply the EJB Remote Interface or do we need to supply both the remote interface and the EJB bean implementation?

From this link [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ejbfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rejb_3stubscmd.html)

it seems only the remote interface is necessary but I cannot conclude.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include the EJB JAR with annotated classes and ejb-jar.xml if relevant.

Prior to EJB 2, ejbdeploy could create stubs for any interface that extends java.rmi.Remote.  As of EJB 3, arbitrary interfaces can be remote interfaces, so the createEJBStubs command needs to start with the set of annotated EJB classes, then determine the set of remote interfaces, and then generate stubs for those remote interfaces.

Comment: When you say EJB jar with annotated classes, you mean the bean class annotated with @Sateless or the Interface annotated with @Remote? Or both?

Comment: Both. (Annoying that stackoverflow has a minimum comment length.)